# Python type text in pop up after openfile() run

Tags: python, tabs, keyboard, enter

I have started Python today.
I am trying to have a code that opens an application, types my username, tabs, types my password and hits enter.

My code so far opens the app awaiting login credentials.

import os

def openFile():
        os.startfile('Pamwin.exe.lnk')

I now want to type my Username and Password in, so I can login really lazyily. 
How do I do that?

my username is Dave and my password is password.

Thank you and I appreciate any lesson in Fundamentals here!

Comment: Whats the question ?

Comment: What application are you running? I suspect the answer to this question will be highly dependent on how the binary you're running works.

Comment: Hi Alex. the application is called Pamwin. The Python version is 3.6.1 
IDLE version 3.6.1